# Ionic how can I make a list that links to other states

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to make an app that will display a list of stores and then when you click on that store it will list the food available with a accordion list

how cann I make a list of links to other states?

```
 <ion-content>
  <ion-list>
  <ion-item><a href="supermacs.html">supermacs</ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  ....
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set a href, ui-sref (ui-router), ng-href (angular core) to the same item and ionic detect this attribute and instead of create a **div** element, create **a** element. For example:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item href='supermacs.html'>supermacs</ion-item>
    <ion-item ui-sref='app.supermacs'>supermacs state of ui router</ion-item>
    <ion-item ng-href='app/supermacs'>url to app/supermacs</ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

This three examples must work.
    ....

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of dynamic hrefs from angular. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref